# Картинка при клике не меняется (Jquery)

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery

Всем добрый день! Проблема в следующем: при нажатии на кнопку , должна появляться другая картинка , но этого не происходит.

---

HTML

```
    <section class="news">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="news__title">
            Новинки
        </div>
        <div class="news__inner">
            <div class="news__items">
                <a class="news__item" href="#">
                        <button class="news__heart"></button>
                        <img class="news__item-img" src="images/news/item-one.png" alt="">
                </a>
                <a class="news__name" href="#">
                        <h4 class="news__name-title">LIB TECH</h4>
                        <h4 class="news__name-subtitle">Мужской Сноуборд</h4>
                        <p class="news__name-price">34392 ₽</p>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Вот сама кнопка которая должна менять картинку:

```
<button class="news__heart"></button>
```

В самом низу индекса подключено

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/libs.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/main.js"></script>
```

---

CSS

```
.news{
&__items{
    width: 320px;    
}
&__item{
    padding: 50px 25px;
    background-color: #F9F9F9;
    position: relative;
}
&__name{
    display: block;
}
&__heart{
    position: absolute;
    right: 15px;
    top: 15px;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    z-index: 5;
    background-color: transparent;
    border: transparent;
    outline: none;
    &::before{
        content: "";
        position: absolute;
        right: 0;
        top: 0;
        width: 40px;
        height: 40px;
        background-image: url('../images/news/zvezda.svg');
    }
    &--active::before{
        background-image: url('../images/news/active.svg');
    }

}
```

}

---

JS

```
 $(function(){


$('.slider-main__inner').slick({
    infinite: true,
    speed: 300,
    slidesToShow: 1,
    centerMode: true,
    variableWidth: true
});

$('.news__heart').on('click', function(){
    $('.news__heart').toggleClass('.news__heart--active')
});
});
```

Comment: А что консоль говорит?

Comment: @BearVorkuta ничего(

Comment: ToggleClass в скобках точку перед названием класса не надо ставить

Comment: @BearVorkuta , омг , это работает, смотрел в код как слепой и ничего не увидел, спасибо тебе огромное